# How to rename export animation frames numerally with "steps"?

Tags: animation, export

If I export my animation (into png) the files are named "001", "002", "003", etc.This is good. but when I change the frame "step" in output properties to something like "2", the files are now exported as "001", "003", "005". I understand why this is happening but how can I make it so it exports how it was before, but with the different "step" option?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect? What do you mean by '...so it exports how it was before, but with the different "step" option?'

Comment: So basically i want the final result to be "001", "002", "003". with the changed "steps"

Comment: Ah, I see. Step=2 skips every 2nd frame. Output is "frame001.png", "frame003.png", "frame005.png", etc. But you want to have them saved as "frame001.png", "frame002.png", "frame003.png", etc and it's actually the frames 1, 3, 5, etc. Sequential numbering with a changed frame rate

Comment: So i put the put the step value back to one and halved the frame rate, this still gave me 20 frames, rather than the 10 that changing the step value gave me